# troubles calculating the max label height

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im having troubles calculating the max label height of a group of labels. I have the following code:

```
-(double)calcMaxHeight:(NSDictionary *)fields withFont:(UIFont *)font {
    double maxRowHeigth = 0;
    NSArray *keys = [fields allKeys];
    for(NSString *key in keys) {
        NSDictionary *dic = [fields objectForKey:key];
        UILabel *aux = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [aux setNumberOfLines:0];
        [aux setText:[dic objectForKey:@"text"]];
        [aux setFont:font];
        [aux setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake([[dic objectForKey:@"value"] doubleValue],MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize auxSize = [aux sizeThatFits:maxSize];

        if(auxSize.height > maxRowHeigth)
            maxRowHeigth = auxSize.height;
    }
    return maxRowHeigth;
}
```

And this code "works". The problem is that i need to calculate the label size when the text has paddings because, in the `drawTextInRect` method, i add an `UIEdgeInsets`of {3,3,3,3}.

So, how can i calculate the UILabel size counting with the padding? I tried overriding the sizeThatFits method, but im missing something yet:

```
-(CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    NSString *text=self.text;
    double width = size.width - 6;
    CGSize nSize = CGSizeMake(width, size.height);

    CGSize stringSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:nSize
                                           options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine |
                                                   NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : self.font}
                                           context:nil].size;
    return stringSize;
}
```

With this, i cant see the whole text when it occupies more than 1 row.

Thank you.

Regards.

Comment: You're trying to calculate the height of a string ?

Comment: no, im trying to calculate the height of a label with a given font

Comment: Yes but you do that by calculating the size of font on the string. See my Answer:

Comment: Can you add the expected UI

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the height of the string and therefore the label:

```
- (CGSize)sizeForString:(NSString *)text font:(UIFont *)font maxHeight:(CGFloat)maxHeight maxWidth:(CGFloat)maxWidth {

    NSDictionary *stringAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : font};

    CGSize stringLength = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, maxHeight 
                                             options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine | NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin 
                                          attributes:stringAttributes 
                                             context:nil].size;
    return stringLength;
}
```

Comment: nah, i still have the same issue

Comment: and you've passed in the right string and set the correct width and height you want ? using MAXFLOAT if you don't want a max for either height or width.

Comment: yes. I used this call: `CGSize test = [self sizeForString:[dic objectForKey:@"text"] font:font maxHeight:MAXFLOAT maxWidth:[[dic objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue]];`

Comment: What value does [[dic objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue] give you ? and what is in [dic objectForKey:@"text"] ?

Comment: text is Fault group. The width is 60.0. Im using Arial-Bold size 10 font. The calculated height for this is 11.171875

Comment: Well that sounds right ... 'Fault Group' won't be 60 wide so 11.171 is the height of 1 line of text....

Comment: yes but, if you see the image, fault group is 2 lines of text. And also, in the next image, the row height is 22.343750, and all texts occupy 1 line

Comment: Are you sure its' size 10 font ? that seems a lot smaller than what is appearing on your screen shot ?

Comment: Also you've called sizeThatFits, that resizes the text to fit the label size so may overide the font size you've chosen

Comment: Also Arial-Bold isn't a valid font ? Should it be Arial-BoldMT ?

Comment: yes, but i used your method to make the new calculus. And yes, the font is Arial-BoldMT. I get it from an XML: <titleFont>
                    <size>10</size>
                    <name>Arial-BoldMT</name>
                    <color>000000</color>
                </titleFont>

Comment: i changed the question. Maybe youll want to delete this answer